# Summation of inputted numbers in c

Tags: c

I am working with this line of code my problem is every time i input a number the value of my sum is not updating. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int condition(int a)
 {
    int i=0, sum=0;
    if (a%2 == 0)
    {
        printf("Please input ODD numbers only");
    }
    if (a%2 != 0)
    {
        sum=sum+a;
        printf("\nTotal of ODD number is %d",sum);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i, j, n;
    printf("Total number: ");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    i=0;
    while(i<j)
    {
        printf("\nNumber %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d",&n);
        condition(n);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
 Total number: 3
 Number 1: 3
 Total of ODD number is 3
 Number 2: 5
 Total of ODD number is 8
 Number 3: 7
 Total of ODD number is 15
```

Comment: You need to remove `i` from the `condition` function, as it's not used in there, and make `sum` a static variable, so that its value doesn't get overridden by its start value every time the function is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum was initialized to 0 in every round of the loop. Do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int condition(int a, int sum)
 {
    int i=0;
    if (a%2 == 0)
    {
        printf("Please input ODD numbers only");
    }
    if (a%2 != 0)
    {
        sum=sum+a;
        printf("\nTotal of ODD number is %d",sum);
        return sum;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int i, j, n, sum=0;
    printf("Total number: ");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    i=0;
    while(i<j)
    {
        printf("\nNumber %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d",&n);
        sum = condition(n, sum);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And remember to return a value if your function is not void.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you want to make sum global (i.e. not set to zero every time you call 'condition')

```cpp
// make the sum global
int sum = 0;

 int condition(int a)
 {
    if(a%2==0)
    {
        printf("Please input ODD numbers only");
    }
    if(a%2!=0)
    {
        sum=sum+a;
        printf("\nTotal of ODD number is %d",sum);
    }
}
```